# ASP.NET Core MVC async and injectable ViewLocationExpander?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**First:** The `IViewLocationExpander` interface dose not expose async methods, i am 
wondering if it's not supported at all or it is some where buried in docs?

What i need is to perform some database call and expand view locations based on the result of that.

**Second:** currently when you are going to register a `ViewLocationExpander` you need to instantiate it directly and pass the instance to `ViewLocationExpanders` which makes it hard to have parameters in `ViewLocationExpander` constructor, any workaround for that is also highly appreciated.

This is what should be done currently:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(c =>
{
     c.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CustomExpander());
});
```